# Validate address with Bing Maps api

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, bing-maps

I'm working with a plugin for CRM Dynamics 2011 both online and enterprise.

I have to validate the address using bing maps and then show the Latitud and lognitud. I find how to get the lat/long of a valid address but I can't figure out how to valid that address.

I'm using GeocodeService to retrieve latitud and longitud and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to verify that the address is an existing one then you can check if the web service returns valid values.
If you need to match the address with a company name, then retrieve the address for the company and then compare it to the one you already had.